# Android: new class variable initialization

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I have two classes(activites) in android:

1. ProfileScreen.
2. FillDetailScreen.

Now from activity 1 I am calling activity 2 by following code:

```
Intent it = new Intent(ProfileScreen.this, FillDetailsScreen.class);        
startActivity(it);
```

But I have some class variables in FillDetailsScreen, how can I initialize them from my activity 1 that is ProfileScreen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply declare the class variable **static** and initailze them in the ProfileScreen class using **FillDetailsScreen.varName=value** .

Answer (score 1):

you should pass their values in the intent:

```
it.putExtra("param1", var1);
it.putExtra("param2", var2);
```

---

in FillDetailScreen:

```
intent = getIntent();
var1 = intent.getExtra("param1");
```

Comment: My variables are complex objects like SoapObject rather than simple string or others which are accepted by putExtra. What to do now? :(

Comment: Save it to somewhere. YOu can put data to database ,or serialize to a file in internal or extrnal storage, or just put the data to shared preference.